# How to split Indian states and provinces from world states and provinces shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, geojson, maps, d3, topojson

I am following Mike Bostock's D3 [Lets make a map](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) to create GeoJSON for states and provinces of a country. I got a shapefile for states and provinces from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/). I am trying to extract info for India with this command:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -where "ADM1_A3 IN ('IND')" subunits.json ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.shp
```

Here is the error:

> GeoJSON driver failed to create subunits.json

Is there any ISO country code for Admin-1 level?

Comment: What precisely are you seeing when it's not working?

Comment: "not working" isn't a description of the problem - if it worked, you wouldn't be here! Instead, say what you expected to happen, and what happened instead. We can't see the screen, you have to describe it to us exactly.

Comment: sorry i updated the question  :(

Answer (score 1):

I can use the same command for states and provinces too with AMD0 as:

> ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -where "ADM0_A3 IN ('IND')" subunits.json ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.shp

and one more working solution is:

> ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -where "gu_a3 = 'USA'" subunits.json ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.shp